# Why does sed match something outside the group as part of the group?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, terminal

I was trying to use sed recently to generate a bunch of methods from comma-and-newline separated enumeration members. I ran into the following behavior which seems unintuitive:

```
$ echo 'Hello,' | sed 's/\(.*\),\?/"Hi \1!"/g'
"Hi Hello,!"
```

Here I'm trying to capture everything before the comma into a group via `\(.*\)`, then I allow an optional comma with `,\?`. I expected this to replace `\1` with everything before the first comma, namely `Hello`, but for some reason the comma is getting included in the substitution too although it is not inside the group. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions do greedy matching (from left to right) by default, backtracking if the greediest match doesn't work. So in the case of `\(.*\),\?`, the greediest match is to match `Hello,` to the `\(.*\)` and nothing to the `,\?`.

I'm not sure how to do non-greedy matching in basic regular expressions (which is what `sed` uses). In Perl-style regular expressions (not used by `sed`), you put a question mark after the matching operator, so you'd use something like `(.*?),?`.

The next best thing you can do is to use something like `\([^,]*\),\?`, but then it'd stop matching at the first comma it sees.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `sed` Regex is greedy and the `?` quantifier means to match 0 or 1 of the preceding token -- `,` in this case.

So, here the engine greedily matches till the end, and as the `?` is made optional by `?`, it is being included too within the captured group `(.*)`.

To get the desired behavior, drop `?`:

```
%  echo 'Hello,' | sed 's/\(.*\),\?/"Hi \1!"/g'
"Hi Hello,!"

%  echo 'Hello,' | sed 's/\(.*\),/"Hi \1!"/g' 
"Hi Hello!"
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. The comma at the end needs to be optional, because I'm trying to match against enum members and the last one doesn't have a trailing comma.